# Is there a way to copy/paste with iterm2 on osx over ssh with tmux and vim?

Tags: macos, ssh, vim, tmux, clipboard

Given I am SSHed into a server and have tmux running, is there any straightforward way to be able to yank into a register in vim and:

- have that text be available in my tmux clipboard?
- have that text available in my osx clipboard?

I know how to copy/paste in tmux and iterm2 seems to handle passing that onto my osx clipboard. However there are times when I want to yank text in a vim split screen and the tmux copy/paste won't do. Anyone figured this out?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer, but for me the combination of https://github.com/wincent/clipper and https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard plus a few tmux and vim keybindings described on those pages works wonders.

Comment: @echristopherson Does it work when the ssh-server is running on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to create a vim function that uses `redir` or `writefile` to dump the yanked register into a file, use `tmux load-buffer` to get it into the tmux clipboard, and then delete the file.

To get the remote tmux clipboard into the OS X clipboard, I use `ssh HOST tmux show-buffer | pbcopy`.

Both of these are kind of annoying, but I don't know of any better ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Not ideal, but I appreciate the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Part of your answer is to run tmux locally on your mac before you SSH out.  Then you are working with your local tmux to copy/paste.  Again, not super ideal if you need to grab more lines of code in a remote vim session that are greater in size than your current screen, but it works for most scenarios.